# Which Maven JavaFX dependencies does my project need?

Tags: maven, javafx

There are several JavaFX Maven dependencies:

- javafx
- javafx-controls
- javafx-graphics
- javafx-fxml

What do each of these dependencies contain? For example, I noticed that if I remove the javafx-fxml dependency, part of my code for loading FXML files breaks.

So what is the high-level objective of each dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm)

> JavaFX is a set of graphics and media packages that enables developers
> to design, create, test, debug, and deploy rich client applications
> that operate consistently across diverse platforms.

[JavaFX Controls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html)

> Base class for all user interface controls. A "Control" is a node in
> the scene graph which can be manipulated by the user. Controls provide
> additional variables and behaviors beyond those of Node to support
> common user interactions in a manner which is consistent and
> predictable for the user.

[JavaFX Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx.graphics-summary.html)

> Defines the core scenegraph APIs for the JavaFX UI toolkit (such as
> layout containers, application lifecycle, shapes, transformations,
> canvas, input, painting, image handling, and effects), as well as APIs
> for animation, css, concurrency, geometry, printing, and windowing.

[JavaFx FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html)

> Loads an object hierarchy from an XML document.

Answer (score 1):

There are more modules than the ones you have mentioned already. You find the full list here in the official documentation.
https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/